# Why does Java delete the blank space between paragraphs during conversion to PDF?

Tags: java, itext, pdf-generation

Why is Java deleting the spaces between paragraphs? I'm using iText5 to convert an .rtf file into PDF. The file contains reports and each report is on its own page. After converting, the spaces between paragraphs are deleted making the paging not the same as it was before converting.

I tried using Rectangle to set the page size, but since the report doesn't have the same number of lines, some reports still share the same page with other reports.

```
//Set PDF layout
//Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle (0, 0, 1350, 16615);
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate());
document.setMargins(13, 0, 10, 10);           
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
document.open();

br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(TEXT));

String line;
Paragraph p;       
//PDF font configuration
Font normal = new Font(FontFamily.COURIER, 5);
Font bold = new Font(FontFamily.COURIER, 5, Font.BOLD);

//add page to PDF       
boolean title = true;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {               
    p = new Paragraph(line, title ? bold : normal);
        document.add(p);
     }           
        document.close();
```

I don't want the program to delete spaces between paragraphs.

Comment: You can try replacing your spaces with [\u00a0](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm).

Comment: Java isn't *doing* anything; the library that you're using to accomplish this is the cause, and if there isn't a setting to disable, you'll need to fork it (assuming that it's open source) and modify the code yourself.

Comment: I use a different library to convert .rtf to .pdf format, but the principle is the same. 1. Convert blank paragraphs in the .rtf document to linefeeds. *Replace the regular expression `^$` by `QQQ` and then replace QQQ by `\n`*. It would be faster to convert `^$` directly to `\n` but my word processor doesn't allow me to do it in a single step. 2. After I have a perfectly formatted .rtf I convert the .rtf to .pdf.

Comment: (@karel - are you saying / implying that the problem is that the OP's ".rtf" file is *incorrectly* formatted?  Not "conformant" RTF?)

Comment: Are you sure that source file really is a rtf file? In that case your result likely has rtf instructions all over it. That being said, in case of empty lines read you should at least use a string with a space instead of that empty line when creating a `Paragraph` because paragraphs without content don't have a height...

Comment: Add your input .rtf file to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### First off

I doubt that your input really is a rtf file. A rtf file looks like this

```
{\rtf1\ansi{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss Helvetica;}\f0\pard
This is some {\b bold} text.\par
}
```

*(from [Wikipedia about Rich Text Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format))*

If you feed that file into your code, you get something like

[image: screen shot]

which presumably is not what you want.

So let's assume your input is plain text which you read line by line.

#### How to prevent dropped empty lines

Please be aware that a `Paragraph` constructed from the empty string requires virtually no vertical space, e.g.

```
doc.add(new Paragraph("1 Between this line and line 3 there is an empty paragraph."));
doc.add(new Paragraph(""));
doc.add(new Paragraph("3 This is line 3."));
doc.add(new Paragraph("4 Between this line and line 6 there is a paragraph with only a space."));
doc.add(new Paragraph(" "));
doc.add(new Paragraph("6 This is line 6."));
```

*([EmptyParagraphs](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/content/EmptyParagraphs.java#L39) test `testEmptyParagraphsForFazriBadri`)*

results in

[image: screen shot]

Observe that line 2 effectively is dropped.

The reason is that the `Paragraph(String string)` constructor is a convenience shortcut,

```
p = new Paragraph(string);
```

is essentially equivalent to

```
p = new Paragraph();
if (string != null && string.length() != 0) {
    p.add(new Chunk(string));
}
```

Thus, for `new Paragraph("")` no chunk is added to the paragraph, it is empty, no vertical space is needed for its chunks.

In such a case you can start playing around with the `Leading`, `SpacingBefore`, or `SpacingAfter` of the paragraph itself or the surrounding paragraphs, but the simplest method surely is to replace the empty string `""` by a string containing a space `" "`.

In your case that could be done by replacing

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {               
    p = new Paragraph(line, title ? bold : normal);
    document.add(p);
}
```

by

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {               
    p = new Paragraph(line.length() == 0 ? " " : line, title ? bold : normal);
    document.add(p);
}
```